# Перебор массива из объекта

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

У меня сложилась такая ситуация что я не могу перебрать данные из массива. Я пользуюсь **React+Redux** получаю данные в виде объекта и храню в редаксе. Теперь в UI компоненте хочу работать с этими данными. Но при переборе у меня выдает ошибку ***(cannot read property 'map' of undefined)***. Я пробовал `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()`. Даже пробовал при получение разделить данные и потом задиспатчит но, в итоге возвращаюсь в начало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
          {
                messages.messages.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <GetMessageText key={index}>
                            {data.message}
                        </GetMessageText>
                    )
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

что из этого вам сообщения не понятно?

> cannot read property 'map' of undefined

перевод

> невозможно прочитать свойство 'map' из undefined

поставте точку останова, и посмотрите почему там пусто

Comment: С сообщением все понятно, долго искал не смог понят в чем причина и обратился сюда за помощью

Comment: в чем проблема перед messages.messages.map поставить точку останова?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду breakpoint или debugger, я ставил но при загрузке странице не доходит до поинта и сразу выдает ошибку, можете просто объяснить как правильно извлечь данные ? может в коде я что-то не так делаю или функция у меня не правильная

Comment: из этого следует что ошибка в другом месте и приведенная информация в вопросе полностью бесполезна

Comment: А почему сразу "-" ставит ? если я первый раз задаю вопрос, достаточно было просто объяснить

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте, например, console.log(props) и смотрите, что у вас там приходит.

Если вы получаете данные с сервера, то при первом рендере у вас там приходит массив или какой-нибудь undefined? Всегда учитывайте первый рендер, пока данных еще нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, из сервера я получаю данные. в консоле сперва идет пустой массив ( я так понял изначальный мой стейт) а потом данные из сервере. В консоле я могу вывести (messages.messages) и получи нужные данные, но вот когда запускаю map начинается сложности. Я даже пытался с Object.entries все обернуть в массив и это не помогло

Comment: А почему собственно messages.messages.map()? Может все же нужно просто messages.map().

Как вы получаете этот messages из props?

Comment: Логика такая. получаю дату, обрабатываю и отправляю в редюсер, дальше с помощью connect() соединяю UI и передаю пропс в моем случае messages. Почему messages.messages ? потому что мне нужно замапит данные именно из этого объекта, я пробовал и messages замапить, тоже самое. Мне кажется проблема именно в том что при рендринге сперва я получаю пустой массив а потом данные, и мап начинает наверно пустой массив мапить и получается такая фигня. Пока не могу разобраться почему я получаю пустой массив или undefined

Comment: На пустом массиве map ошибку не вызовет. Посмотрел ваш код. Функция map возвращает новый массив в никуда. Вам нужно написать return messages.messages.map(...);

Comment: Все, Спасибо за советы, я решил эту проблему с методом проверки ( messages.messages ? messages.messages )